# Configure Git in Powerbuilder 12.5

Tags: powerbuilder

I would like to integrate my powerbuilder application with GIT Source version control.I would like to know a step by step process to configure git in my powerbuilder. My powerbuilder version is 12.5.

Thanks

Comment: Just so happy to see that there is someone using PB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with 12.5.  There was a MSSCCI to Git bridge product from PB Software that worked with older versions of Git, but they don't seem to be around anymore:

http://www.pbsoftware.com/index.php/products/powerbuilder-git-msscci-provider/

Native support for Git (and SVN) was added to the 2017 R2 version of the product by Appeon.  I would suggest upgrading to the most recent version of the product (2019 comes out later this month) if you need to support Git:

https://community.appeon.com/index.php/articles/tutorials-articles/2-powerbuilder/183-powerbuilder-2017-r2-new-feature-git-source-control-support

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I will get the git dll's uploaded to the site again. PB Software

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).